# Store and recover objects in powershell

Tags: powershell, class, multidimensional-array, store, recover

I'm making a script where I'm trying to store and recover some objects whit an array inside.
But couldn't get it to work.
Also I'm not sure iff I'm on the right track or there is an better way to do this.
At this point I'm trying to save a complete object in parts.

A neurol network has info and matricies inside, these matricies have 2D array's inside.

Is there a way to store everything in 1 go and am I making this to complicated?

I've tried some things like :

```
            $this | Export-CSV -Path $Path1
            $this.matrix1 | Export-CSV -Path $Path2
            $this.matrix1.data | % { $_ -join ','} |  out-file $Path3
```

But this doesn't get all the data I need to store 
(espacialy the array in $this.matrix1.data )
Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong or know's a better way?
And if so, how can I get it back into $nn2 ?

```
    class Matrix {
        [int]$some_info11
        [int]$some_info21
        [int]$some_info31
        $data
        Matrix($int){
            $this.some_info11 = 1
            $this.some_info21 = 12
            $this.some_info31 = 123

            $row = 4
            $col = 12
            $temp_array = New-Object 'object[,]' $row , $col

            for ($i=0;$i -le $row -1 ; $i++) {
                for ($j=0;$j -le $col -1 ; $j++) {
                    $temp_array[$i,$j] = Get-Random -Maximum 1.0 -Minimum -1.0
                }
            }

            $this.data = $temp_array
        }
    }

    class NeurolNetwork{
        $matrix1
        [int]$some_info1
        [int]$some_info2
        [int]$some_info3

        NeurolNetwork($inp){
            $this.some_info1 = 1
            $this.some_info2 = 12
            $this.some_info3 = 123

            $this.matrix1 = [Matrix]::New($inp)
        }

        export([string]$dir){
            $Path1 = "C:\test\" + $dir + "\nn.txt"
            $Path2 = "C:\test\" + $dir + "\nn_matrix.csv"
            $Path3 = "C:\test\" + $dir + "\nn_matrix_data.csv"

            $this | Export-CSV -Path $Path1
            $this.matrix1 | Export-CSV -Path $Path2
            $this.matrix1.data | % { $_ -join ','} |  out-file $Path3
        }
    }

    Function get_nn([string]$dir){
        # get files from directory and create a new [NeurolNetwork]
    }


    $nn1 = [NeurolNetwork]::New(12)
    $nn1.export("temp_dir")

    $nn2 = get_nn("temp_dir")
```

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do and what error you are getting. I did a convertto-csv to see the output `"matrix1","some_info1","some_info2","some_info3" "Matrix","1","12","123"`
Whats wrong with that?

Comment: IS this a issue of you exporting the data to a object in a file in one line?

Answer (score 1):

it seems what you are trying to do is save everything in a CSV.

CSVs are not good for multidimensional arrays becuase a CSV is Column/Row Based.

It would probably be better to export to json

```
$this | ConvertTo-Json | out-file -FilePath C:\TEST.json
```

outputs

```
{
    "matrix1":  {
                "some_info11":  1,
                "some_info21":  12,
                "some_info31":  123,
                "data":  [
                    0.53464436509397073,
                    -0.21887814962252894,
                    -0.999366649426225,
                    0.590662602144602,
                    ALot more rows like this...
                    ]
                },
    "some_info1":  1,
    "some_info2":  12,
    "some_info3":  123
}
```

If you want to put this info back into a file you would use.

```
$Obj = Get-Content -Path C:\Test.json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: Thanks this works realy great ,...
unfortanly I don't get a 2d array back in the $this.matrix1.data  :( 
Also come to think of it.... *maybe a stupid question* what is the best option getting $obj making a member of [NeurolNetwork] and $obj.martix of [Matrix] ?
*I'm a little new whit powershell*

Comment: What do you mean you dont get a 2d array back?

Comment: I need examples of what you want and what you are getting